# dismissViewControllerAnimated called from a UIAlertController sends me to the RootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I've been trying to dismiss my alert view by calling dismissViewControllerAnimated but unfortunately I'm not getting what I want since it sends me to the rooviewController ("UsersSwippingViewControllerUsers"/"Users") instead of staying in the view controller that presented it (chatViewController)..

Could You please help me out here.
I have attached screenshots of the code I'm using to call dismissViewControllerAnimated and my storyboard to give you a rough idea of what my app looks like. The view controller that the app is taking me to is "UsersSwippingViewControllerUsers"/"Users" when it should be staying in/taking me to ChatViewController.

ScreenShots:

[This is a preview of my app's storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvjwC.png)

[Here is the code I'm using dismissViewControllerAnimated in the handler of the UIAlertAction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3w8v5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `dismissViewControllerAnimated` method in `UIAlertController` action. Doing this you telling your parent view controller instance to be dismissed (note why you use `self` in closure!). And `UIAlertController` have default approach to be dismissed automatically after any button pressed.

Comment: Removing dismissViewControllerAnimated causes the UIAlertController to never be closed/dismissed.

Comment: @Mystic try to add `view.endEditing(true)` line in start of function `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

Answer (score -1):

Change the type of action to .Cancel instead of .Default for the CancelAction and it should work.

self.dismissViewControllerAnimated would only work if called from the presenter view controller, not the presented one.

Hope it helps

Comment: > Change the type of action to .Cancel - this is not necessary. You may keep UIAlertActionStyle.Default.